# A database schema for Tags (eg. each Post has some optional tags)

Tags: sql, architecture, schema, many-to-many

I have a site like SO, Wordpress, etc, where you make a post and u can have (optional) tags against it.

What is a common database schema to handle this? I'm assuming it's a many<->many structure, with three tables.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: why does it matter how SO implements this. better open a new question that is not SO specific (if you are wondering how SO is implementing stuff send Jeff an email)

Comment: true, i'll fix up my question title to make it non SO specific. it was mainly as an example, more than anything.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A three table many to many structure should be fine.

Eg. `Posts, PostsToTags(post_id,tag_id), Tags`

The key is indexing. Make sure you PostsToTags table is indexed both ways (`post_id,tag_id` and `tag_id,post_id`) also if read performance is ultra critical you could introduce an indexed view (which could give you post_name, tag_name)

You will of course need indexes on Posts and Tags as well.

Comment: I was wondering if I was on the right track and it seems to be :)

Answer (score 1):

"I'm assuming it's a many<->many structure, with three tables. Anyone have any ideas?"

More to the point, there aren't any serious alternatives, are there?  Two relational tables in a many-to-many relationship require at least an association table to carry all the combination of foreign keys.

Does SO do this?  Who knows.  Their data model includes reference counts, and -- for all any knows -- date time stamps and original creator and a lot of other junk about the tag.

Minimally, there have to be three tables.

What they do on SO is hard to know.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure if this is what SO uses.  But there is a good discussion [here](http://www.pui.ch/phred/archives/2005/04/tags-database-schemas.html).

Answer (score 0):

It would be a good idea to loook at how wordpress handles tags for posts and it will give you some idea.

Answer (score -1):

The other possibility of course is that there are only two tables.

Given there are at most 5 tags, a Question table with five nullable foreign-key references to a Tag table is a possiblity.

Not very normalized, but it could be more performant.

Comment: unlikely this will be more performant. it introduces horrendously complex queries when you are looking for multiple tags.

Comment: what if the tags were stored in one delimited varchar field and you could use a "like '%tag%'" query against that field, probably still not very indexable

Comment: @sambo99 - true in that case and good point.  Finding questions for a particular tag would suck.