# How do you count and format user tags

Tags: php, mysql

I have user entered tags that go under the table field tags.

```
$sql="SELECT tags from table";
$stmt16 = $conn->prepare($sql);
$result=$stmt16->execute();
while($row = $stmt16->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){ 
echo $tags=$row['tags'];
}
```

This produces

> cool,yes,okcool,yes,ok

because there are 2 entries with the same 3 tags under that field. I want to be able to count how many duplicates there are of each tag such that the result should be cool(2) yes(2) ok(2). Anyone know the proper way to approach this? Should I fetch the results as an array or explode them?

Comment: If you are really storing tags in a comma-separated field with `cool,yes,ok` then, before doing anything more, **STOP**. And **READ THIS**: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-comma-separated-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With your current data structure, the answer I'd give is yes: as you said, explode them, and put them into an array.

```
$tags = array();
while($row = $stmt16->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){ 
    foreach(explode(',',$row['tags']) as $tag) {
        if(isset($tags[$tag]) {$tags[$tag]++;} else {$tags[$tag]=1;}
    }
}

//now you can see how many times each tag occurred...
foreach($tags as $tag=>$count) {
   print "Tag {$tag} occurred {$count} times<br />";
}
```

However, if you can change the database structure, you'll find it a lot easier to manage your tags if you only have one per DB record. It will make it a lot easier to query them that way.

Comment: I think he just missed to `,` between `okcool` so he already has this structure :-)

Comment: @DKSan -- in the question, he's not outputting anything other than the content of `$row['tags']`, so since the output includes commas, those commas must be in the data. Therefore I read that as meaning he's got two records, both containing "cool,yes,ok" as comma-separated strings. But he wants to know how many "ok" and how many "cool" there are, so with that data structure, he'll have to explode them first. It would be better to have each tag in a separate row, ie 6 rows, with one tag each rather than 2 rows with three tags in CVS format.

Comment: I get the error explode expects at least 2 parameters so when I change it to explode(',',$row['tags']) I get undefined index cool undefined index yes undefined index ok undefined index in on line 24 which is the line that contains $tags[$tag]++; Also, regarding database structure, each entry represents a topic and has the field tags. Do you think I should create a separate tag table and link it with the topic id and have 10 tag fields like tag1 tag2 tag3 etc for each topic entry? Wouldn't that be inefficient?

Comment: @Scarface: You would add a `Tag` table and a `TagTopic` association table (and completely drop the `tags` field you have).

Comment: I read that post ypercube, I am seeing the pitfalls of what I am doing now. It is good to learn when you are doing something wrong rather than just a way to make it work. So the user enters tags in a form like tag1,tag2,tag3. I use some preg function to separate them and insert them separately into the table. How would Tag and TagTopic be structured? I assume Tag would store tags in single entries like tag1 is one entry and it can have a topic_id as well. So why TagTopic?

Comment: re missing param on explode -- oops, my bad; fixed it in the answer.<br />Re undefined index: this is only a warning, but you could avoid it by doing `isset($tags[$tag) {$tags[$tags]++;} else {$tags[$tag]=1;}`.<br />Re creating a separate tag table: yes, this is a good idea, but don't have multiple fields; have a table with one tag, with a linking ID back to the topic, and then have multiple tag records per topic.

Comment: First, thanks again Spudley. So there would be 2 fields, tag, and topic_id. 3 tags for a topic would be 3 entries right? Also, lets say the tag entry method is like youtube, one input field with tags separated by commas. If the user then wrote some new tags in the input field but some of the existing ones were still there, would you then just delete all tags with that topic_id and re-insert all the tags? It seems cumbersome if you would have to check if tags exist before updating.

Comment: @Scarface: See the accepted answer to this question (think of "post" instead of "topic"): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/640882/a-database-schema-for-tags-eg-each-post-has-some-optional-tags I could add more detailed answer later.

Comment: @Scarface: Oh, see this nice page with various attermpts: What I propose is the **"Toxi"** solution: http://www.pui.ch/phred/archives/2005/04/tags-database-schemas.html

Comment: Excellent resources ypercube. Thanks a lot, however do you know the point of the second table in the toxi solution; the tagmap? Why not just have a topic_id column for the tags table and match them with each topic?

Comment: @Scarface: yes, those two fields. Best practice would be to also have a unique ID field for each record so you can reference them individually even if the data is the same.

Comment: @Scarface: the `Tagmap`is what I called earlier "association table". It's used in many-to-many relationships. Like yours (a topic can have many tags, a tag can "tag" many topics)

Comment: Alright I got things going, you guys are the best, thanks again for your time! I wish I could up-vote more!

Answer (score 2):

I would alter the statement to

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as cnt, tags 
FROM table
GROUP BY tags
```

and there you are.

**Edit:**
Don't forget to alter your `echo` to `echo $row['tags'] ."(". $row['count'] .")";`

Answer (score 1):

Simply with this query:

```
SELECT tag, COUNT(*)
FROM table
GROUP BY tag
HAVING COUNT(*) >1;
```